# Is there an API for IBM Cloud PowerPC Virtual server instances - power-iaas?

Tags: ibm-cloud, aix, powerpc

I am looking to implement support for legacy AIX services that can scale.

What I would like is to create an AIX VM or at least start a VM programatically.

Is there an API for this.

I have found CLI at

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/power-iaas-cli-plugin?topic=power-iaas-cli-plugin-power-iaas-cli-reference

I have checked https://cloud.ibm.com/docs?tab=api-docs

I have checked the requests made by the web page.
I see it uses cloud.ibm.com/graphql/doServer

with payload like

```
{"operationName":"doServer",
"variables":{"serverId":"SOME-ID","action":"start"}
"query":"mutation doServer($serverId: String!, $action: String!)
{\n  PowerDoServer(serverId: $serverId, action: $action)
{\n    success\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [referenced API docs for IBM Cloud compute](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs?tab=api-docs&category=compute). There is a [set of APIs dealing with Power Virtual Machines](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/power-cloud#introduction) and it has a [REST API to create a new instance](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/power-cloud#pcloud-pvminstances-post).